# I need to do redirect in functions.php

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I use contact form 7 and I save my data in bbdd when the form is fill. For that use:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_form' );

function save_form( $wpcf7 ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

  if ( $submission ) {
       $submited = array();
       $submited['title'] = $wpcf7->title();
       $submited['posted_data'] = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    $data = array(
      'empresa'  => $submited['posted_data']['your-empresa'],
      'nombre'  => $submited['posted_data']['your-nombre'],
      'apellido' => $submited['posted_data']['your-apellidos'],
    );
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'usuarios';
    $success = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    //wp_redirect( "/info-contratar/" );
    //header("Location: /info-contratar/"); exit();
}
```

When functions end. I need use other view: info-contactar, but it never doing redirect. Only I see a Get request with firebug tool.

How can I do redirect and show my page info-contratar?

Regards!

Comment: You have tried using `header("Location: /info-contratar/"); exit();`, try adding `exit();` with `wp_redirect`, because it is recommended in documentation.

Comment: I put exit() with wp_redirect and It is the same result. Obviously if i go to the page /info-contratar/, I can watch that page.

Comment: `wp_redirect` uses PHP's `header` function to redirect. `header` states, that it must be called before any output on the page. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AJAX to submit your contact form 7 data ( which is turned on by default ) you won't be able to redirect using the `wpcf7_before_send_mail` hook. You have a few other options though:

1) Turn off WPCF7 AJAX which is packaged into an entire JS flag. This will also turn off JS validation and all around not optimal. [Documentation](http://contactform7.com/loading-javascript-and-stylesheet-only-when-it-is-necessary/). Add this to wp config

```
define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```

---

2) Use the built-in [WPCF7 Additional Settings Field](http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) field on your contact form to handle the redirect on submission. It looks something like this:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://yourdomain.com/info-contratar/';"
```

---

3) Use jQuery either on the page or in an external file and listen `mailsent.wpcf7`. [Documentation](http://contactform7.com/2012/09/24/contact-form-7-33/).

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.wpcf7' ).on( 'mailsent.wpcf7', function( e ) {
        window.location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/info-contratar/';
    } );
} );
```

Comment: @davidcm86 which option did you use? i am having the same issue. But in my case i need to alter the submitted data before header redirection
`include("psp_ini.php");
$payment = $psp->payments->create(array(
                "amount" => $amount, etc));
 header("Location: " . $payment->getPaymentUrl());`